# Matching HTML table columns width using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm working on Web project using JavaScript & Bootstrap (and angularjs, but not important here).

I have a table that exceeds the vertical page size. If the user scrolls the page, the table's header becomes invisible (goes above the top of the window). The same if I deploy the table within a scrollable `div`.

What I'm trying to do is to deploy two tables, one for the header and the other for the body, being the last deployed within a vertically scrollable `div`.

Bootstrap automatically sets the dimensions of the table and its columns for both tables, resulting in a mismatch (in width) between the header and the body.

To tackle this, I wrote the following simple function:

```
Adjust_Header_to_Body = function() {

    var l_Header_Table_Name = "Header_Table_" + $scope.Tab_Forward_Info.Tab_ID ;
    var l_Body_Table_Name   = "Body_Table_"   + $scope.Tab_Forward_Info.Tab_ID ;

    var l_Header_Obj = document.getElementById(l_Header_Table_Name) ;
    var l_Body_Obj   = document.getElementById(l_Body_Table_Name  ) ;

    for (var i = 0 ; i < l_Body_Obj.rows[0].cells.length ; i++) {

        console.log("First row - cell " + i + " width: " + l_Body_Obj.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth ) ;

        l_Header_Obj.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth = l_Body_Obj.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth + "px" ;
      //l_Header_Obj.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth = l_Body_Obj.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth ;

    }

}
```

[NOTE: tried with and without the "px" with no difference in the result].

I get no errors at all, the width of the columns are logged into the console, but no changes of any sort can be seen.

I guess this has to do with Bootstrap's auto-resize, but I'm neither sure this is the case nor I know how to force it to honor the new sizes.

### Update

Following Enrico's request, I'm adding here a sample HTML and CODE using one of his suggestions which, unfortunately, is not yielding the desired result:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="TestApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="with=device-width initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">

    <script src="Public_Libs/JQuery/jquery.js"></script> 

    <script src="Public_Libs/angular-1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Public_Libs/angular-1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Public_Libs/angular-1.5.8/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Public_Libs/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Public_Libs/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Public_Libs/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Public_Libs/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src="Public_Libs/Charts/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="Index_Controller.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="Application_Body" ng-controller="Index_Controller" dir="{{Language_Direction}}">

    <div style="width:800px;height:700px;overflow-y:auto;margin:auto">
        <table id="MyTable" class="table table-hover">
            <thead style="display:block;text-align:left">
                <tr style="display:block">
                    <th ng-repeat="One_Header in Data.Headers"> {{One_Header}} </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="display:block">
                <tr ng-repeat="One_Record in Data.Records">
                    <td ng-repeat="One_Column in One_Record">
                        {{One_Column}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Controller's code:

```
var TestApp = angular.module( 'TestApp', ['ngRoute' , 'ngSanitize' ]) ;


/**************************************************************************************************/
/**************************************************************************************************/
/*               Directive to enable addressing elements created programmatically as soon         */
/*                                    as they are fully rendered                                  */
/**************************************************************************************************/
/**************************************************************************************************/

TestApp.directive('onFinishRender', function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                if (scope.$last) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("EventRenderingCompleted");
                }
            }
        };
    });

TestApp.directive('compileDirective', ['$compile', '$parse' , function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch(attr.content, function() {
          element.html($parse(attr.content)(scope));
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }, true);
      }
    }
  }]) ;

TestApp.directive('stringToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return '' + value;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return parseFloat(value, 10);
      });
    }
  };
});


/**************************************************************************************************/
/**************************************************************************************************/
/**************************************************************************************************/

TestApp.controller('Index_Controller' , ['$rootScope' , '$scope' ,  function( $rootScope , $scope ) {

    $scope.Data = {Headers : [] ,
                   Records : []   } ;


    $scope.Data.Headers = ["Header_1" , "Header_2" , "Header_3" , "Header_4" , "Header_5"] ;

    var One_Record ;

    for (var i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
        One_Record = []
        for (var j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) {
            One_Record.push("Row " + (i+1).toString() + " | Col " + (j+1).toString()) ;
        }
        $scope.Data.Records.push(One_Record) ;
    }


}]) ;

/****************************************************************************************************************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting in two tables, make use of css and leave the width management to the browser.

There are atleast two ways for achieving the result.

- make use of `display` and `overflow` css rules - [Example](https://medium.com/@vembarrajan/html-css-tricks-scroll-able-table-body-tbody-d23182ae0fbc)
- make use of `position` - [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp) -  [Jsfiddle in the comments](https://jsfiddle.net/q0h2ja3g/36/)

Comment: Thank you Enrico for the suggestion and examples. Looks promising... Will give it a try and let you know if it works for me. Cheers!!!

Comment: I had the same problem once and I fixed with this solution. I'm sure there's also a j query plugin out there but I can find it right now

Comment: Enrico, I just tested the css-based example and it does not generate the expected result. When scrolling, the whole table moves up and down, header included. I must note that, for testing purposes, I didn't deploy a `style` block and instead added to the `<tr>` of the header the `display:block` part (easier to test).

Comment: If you can post the code in your question I can help you. Otherwise, if you don't mind using a library for it, this is the plugin I've used a few years ago

Comment: Hey Enrico. Please take a look at the sample code added to the original question. As stated there, the result is (unfortunately) not what I expect because: (1) the headers are not correctly aligned to the body columns and (2) the header keeps scrolling along with the body.

Comment: Hello Fdavidov. It is a bit hard for me to work directly on your code because it is not easily replicable. I have created a jsfiddle that should do what you require.
[Link here](https://jsfiddle.net/q0h2ja3g/33/)

Comment: Edited jsfiddle with comments.
[LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/q0h2ja3g/36/)

Comment: Hey Enrico, thanks for the fiddle. I'll try to implement it into my example (above sources), see what I get and let you know about the findings. Again, **thanks!!!**.

Comment: Hello Enrico, I implemented the code you sent (jsfiddle) and, sadly, it does not work for me. Also, there is a small glitch in your code: if you reduce the width of the window (bottom-left in the jsfiddle), it takes a number of "scroll-down/scroll-up cycles for the titles' width to properly adjust to those of the body. Let me know if you want me to add to the question the code as I used it.

Comment: That's not a glitch, it's common behavior that I did not address in my example. It needs a simple handle inside a resize event. Can you create a working example with your code inside jsdiffle or similar instrument?

Comment: Enrico, I must (shamefully) confess that I use that site (or similar), and hence it might take me some time, but I will (and let you know). I really appreciate your willingness and patience...

Comment: Don't worry! I appreciate your gratefulness but there's no need for it. This is stack overflow, as long as people behave correctly when asking for help, there will always be pleasure in helping

Comment: Enrico, I meant **I never used that site (or similar)**. Will try it right now... Thanks!!

Comment: Well, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qwL71eb6/6/) is the fiddle but it has issues with Angularjs. Care to have a look?

Comment: Hello fdavidov. I must have missed the notification. Will look asap

Comment: I'm not an expert on angular so I can't help you with that, I'm sorry. Did you check out [this plugin](http://www.fixedheadertable.com/) I linked a few comments back?

Comment: Enrico, thank you again for your time. I found a (amazingly) simple solution: deploy the header as a separate table **WITHOUT** Bootstrap's class. Then, the adjustment does work (though I still need to fine-tune it with padding widths, etc.).